# Issue with groovy process execution when command has spaces

Tags: groovy

Why do the spaces in the commit message cause `p2` to fail?

```
def envp = null
def repoDir = File.createTempFile("test","txt").getParentFile()

Process p = "git init".execute(null, repoDir)
p.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)

/////////////

println "Commit1 start"
Process p1 = "git commit --allow-empty -m \"Commit1\"".execute(null, repoDir)
p1.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)
println "Commit1 done"


/////////////

println "Commit2 start"
Process p2 = "git commit --allow-empty -m \"Commit number 2\"".execute(null, repoDir)
p2.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)
println "Commit2 done"
```

Comment: Have you tried `"git commit --allow-empty -m 'Commit number 2'"`? With single quotes.

Comment: Yes. Tried that also. Didn't work. I'm on Mac Mavericks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code solves your problem:

```
println "Commit2 start"
Process p2 = ["git", "commit", "--allow-empty", "-m \"Commit number 2\""].execute(null,  repoDir)
p2.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)
println "Commit2 done
```

The use of array (instead of string) as a workaround for quoted-argument-with-spaces problem is documented here:
http://groovy.codehaus.org/Executing+External+Processes+From+Groovy